# FireFox randomly breaks login?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-2, forms-authentication

**Update:** I finished my app using NerdDinner 1.0 as a starting point. NerdDinner 2.0 had a more robust AccountController so I line for line did a complete replace of my AccountController v1. It was at this point that I started having login issues with FireFox (confirmed with a revision rollback). There are several differences on the whole that are in NerdDinner 2.0 that I do want to implement until I understand them. If someone could please take a looksy at AccountController between the two tuts and let me know what the extra piece of the puzzle preventing me from dropping v2 in is I would greatly appreciate it. I can post any and all of my code as needed.

NerdDinner 1: http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/releases/view/24504
NerdDinner 2: http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/releases/view/45621

---

I'm using an ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider along with the NerdDinner tutorial to authenticate a user. In firefox my logins aren't working anymore, but in IE they are working just fine. I've tried clearing all cache/cookies/etc as well as a mixture of Build->Clean/rebuild/build. Occasionally I'll get it working again but I can't figure out the source or solution.

Debugging doesn't show anything wrong but my login is not sticking.

Anyone seen this before? Any ideas? I can post any code but I don't think it's relevant as it was working at one time in all my browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this.  It was a mix of things that aren't all necessarily described here.  If anyone really wants the complete before/after I can post it but I'll assume no :)